# Why this apparently "random" numbers print "Java is Awesome"

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream, ascii

How does this program print "Java is Awesome"?

```
String s = IntStream.of(1635148106, 544434464, 1936029505, 6647151)
                    .flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, 4).map(i -> e >> i * 8))
                    .mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((byte) i))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little help for you:

```
01001010 01100001 01110110 01100001 (avaJ)
00100000 01101001 01110011 00100000 ( si )
01000001 01110111 01100101 01110011 (sewA)
01101111 01101101 01100101           (emo)
```

Now read it backwards:

```
01100001 01110110 01100001 01001010
00100000 01110011 01101001 00100000
01110011 01100101 01110111 01000001
00000000 01100101 01101101 01101111
```

Which is nothing but:

```
1247901281
543781664
1098343795
1869440256
```

Answer (score 8):

The `IntStream.of(1635148106, 544434464, 1936029505, 6647151)` creates a stream of 4 elements. Then, for each of those elements, we will do

```
e -> IntStream.range(0, 4).map(i -> e >> i * 8)
```

which basically creates 4 elements resulting from the operations

```
e >> 0
e >> 8
e >> 16
e >> 24
```

So, the entire operation `e -> IntStream.range(0, 4).map(i -> e >> i * 8)` on the elements `IntStream.of(1635148106, 544434464, 1936029505, 6647151)` results in:

```
1635148106 6387297 24950 97
544434464  2126697 8307  32
1936029505 7562615 29541 115
6647151    25965   101   0
```

The `flatMap(...)` part converts the previous operation to an `IntStream`.

Then in the next operation:

```
mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((byte) i))
```

first `(byte) i` is applied therefore:

```
1635148106 6387297 24950 97
544434464  2126697 8307  32
1936029505 7562615 29541 115
6647151    25965   101   0
```

becomes:

```
74 97 118 97
32 105 115 32
65 119 101 115
111 109 101 0
```

which if you look at the ASCII table:

[image]

corresponds to :

```
JAVA
<space>is<space>
Awes
ome<null>
```

The remaining operations:

```
.mapToObj(i -> Character.toString((byte) i))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

just convert it to a `String` representation.

For those wondering how from

```
1635148106 6387297 24950 97
544434464  2126697 8307  32
1936029505 7562615 29541 115
6647151    25965   101   0
```

you get:

```
74 97 118 97
32 105 115 32
65 119 101 115
111 109 101 0
```

First, convert the first elements into binary, and since one byte is 8 bits, extract the last 8 bits of that binary, and convert the same back to decimal. For instance:

```
1635148106
```

in binary is

```
1100001011101100110000101001010
```

The last 8 bits:

```
01001010
```

in decimal is `74`.

Or convert into hexadecimal `1635148106` -> `6176614A` exact relevant part (*the byte*) -> `4A` and look directly into the ASCII table -> `J`.